# Why asp.net validators prevent all other postback?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a page with some linkbuttons and a loginform validates by asp.net validators . 
when user click in linkbuttons validators prevent postback . linkbuttons are none of loginform business and validtors shouldnt validate when linkbuttons clicked .

What can i do?

tnx in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two parts to work with.

1. you can set a `ValidationGroup`
2. you can set the controls that are not being used in the validation process to `CausesValidation=False`

Some info on ValidationGroups can be found on [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx)
Some info on CausesValidation can be found at [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102902/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112305-1.aspx)

These can work hand-in-hand or individually to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `CausesValidation` property of the `LinkButton` to `false`, to prevent validation.

Answer (score 3):

set a different group for the validators u dont want to be validated when button is clicked
this can be done by "ValidationGroup" property