# Cannot update fields in Gridview when in "Edit" mode, asp validators prevents updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview, customvalidator

On my final year project I'm using a **GridView** that use an **ObjectDataSource** to show database data.
My **ObjectDataSource** is linked with proper *"select", "update", "delete"* functions that are part of a N-Tiers application.

I've tested all my functions and they work well.

But when in "*Edit"* mode of the GridView I cannot update my fields... However I can delete rows well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE: The problem is that my asp client-side *validators* are preventing me from submitting the updated field in "edit" mode.
I've added them to the code.**

Partial code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>        
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="BeersObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
        DeleteMethod="DeleteBeer_BLL"
        SelectMethod="RetrieveBeers_BLL" 
        UpdateMethod="UpdateBeer_BLL"
        TypeName="BLL" >
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="logoPath" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>        
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="BeersObjectDataSource" PageSize="7" 
    onrowdeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" DataKeyNames="id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID"  
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Beer Name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="country" HeaderText="Beer Country" 
            SortExpression="country" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="logoPath" HeaderText="Image Path"
            SortExpression="logoPath" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="logoPath" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/{0}" 
                HeaderText="Logo Preview" NullDisplayText="No image" 
                NullImageUrl="~/images/logobeers/no-photo.jpg" 
                SortExpression="logoPath" ReadOnly="True">
                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px" />
        </asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxBeerName" runat="server">Beer Name</asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxBeerName" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="*" 
    onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True" 
    ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxBeerCountry" runat="server">Beer Country</asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxBeerCountry" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="*" 
    onservervalidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True" 
    ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload to DataBase" 
    onclick="Button1_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="uploadStatusLabel" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Partial Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid == true)
    {    /* SOME CODE ..... */    }
}
```

Comment: Check your `UpdateBeer_BLL` method.

Comment: @afzalulh I have double check my method and the problem is not coming from it, but comming from the validators (see my edited post). Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That answer help me:
[Why asp.net validators prevent all other postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891816/why-asp-net-validators-prevent-all-other-postback)

I've made a **ValidationGroup**:

Added the property `ValidationGroup="AddBeerValidationGroup"` to each **CustomValidator**

Partial  modified Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("AddBeerValidationGroup");

    if (Page.IsValid == true)
    {  /* SOME CODE ..... */    }
}
```